# htaccess RewriteRule subfolder

Tags: .htaccess

I have some script that work good in root of domain folder. When i move everyting in subfolder i get 404 error or root redirection.

I think problem is in .htaccess

```
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule move/(.*)/ m.php?q=$1
RewriteRule move/(.*) m.php?q=$1
```

What i need to change for example that page is not in root folder but in www.domain.com/subfolder

Thank you

Comment: Was the answer helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you do not need mod_rewrite here since mod_alias handles your specific case nicely, that's what I'd use:

```
Redirect 301 / /subfolder/
```

If you find this does not do the trick and behaves "loopy" you can still make use mod_rewrite like that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^subfolder/
RewriteRule .? subfolder%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```